# Trying to add click event by addEventListener to a button inside function but [object HTMLButtonElement] showed up

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-5

I tried to get 3 inputs and store them by clicking on a button, then by the result, i wanted to show a message and create a button next to the message simultaneously.

I did the second part by creating a button with **createElement** and adding a click event to it by **addEventListener** inside a function but it showed the **[object HTMLButtonElement]** in the browser instead of the new button.

i've read related questions but i couldn't figure it out through them.

HTML:

```
<h2>Enter keys</h2>
<input type="text" id="key1" placeholder="key1">
<input type="text" id="key2" placeholder="key2">
<input type="text" id="key3" placeholder="key3">
<button onclick="jsonSend()">Save</button>
<p id="demo"></p>
```

JS:

```
var obj, myJSON, showJSON, textSC, text2, outObj;

function jsonSend(){
    obj = {};
    obj.key1 = document.getElementById("key1").value;
    obj.key2 = document.getElementById("key2").value;
    obj.key3 = document.getElementById("key3").value;

    //storing data
    myJSON = JSON.stringify(obj);
    localStorage.setItem("testJSON", myJSON);

    //new button
    showJSON = document.createElement("button");
    showJSON.setAttribute("id", "showJSON");
    textSC = document.createTextNode("Show info");
    showJSON.appendChild(textSC);
    showJSON.addEventListener("click", showFunc);
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "data stored successfully... 
    <br>" + showJSON;
}

function showFunc(){
    text2 = localStorage.getItem("testJSON");
    outObj = JSON.parse(text2);
    console.log(outObj);
}
```

Comment: You're appending a JavaScript Object to a string, which coerces the Object to a string. Instead, you should probably append the Object using `document.getElementById('demo').appendChild(showJSON)`.

Comment: ^^^ `=` the text part to the innerHTML, and then appendChild the showJSON to it.

Comment: @DavidThomas that's it, now it's working properly without any error, you saved the day.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can not add `button` by adding text into `innerHtml`. `button` is an object, not a text. So, you must use `appendChild` method to add one `HtmlElement` to another.

```js
var obj, myJSON, showJSON, textSC, text2, outObj;

// for testing only, delete localStorageF and use localStorage
var localStorageF = {
 setItem(key, value) {
    localStorageF[key] = value;
    console.log("stored key: ", key, "; value: ", value);
 },
 getItem(key) {
   return localStorageF[key];
 }
};

function jsonSend(){
  obj = {};
  obj.key1 = document.getElementById("key1").value;
  obj.key2 = document.getElementById("key2").value;
  obj.key3 = document.getElementById("key3").value;

  //storing data
   myJSON = JSON.stringify(obj);
  localStorageF.setItem("testJSON", myJSON);

  //new button
  showJSON = document.createElement("button");
  showJSON.setAttribute("id", "showJSON");
  textSC = document.createTextNode("Show info");
  showJSON.appendChild(textSC);
  showJSON.addEventListener("click", showFunc);
  var demo = document.getElementById("demo")
  demo.innerHTML = "data stored successfully...<br/>";
  demo.appendChild(showJSON)
}

function showFunc(){
  text2 = localStorageF.getItem("testJSON");
  outObj = JSON.parse(text2);
  console.log(outObj);
}
```

```html
<h2>Enter keys</h2>
<input type="text" id="key1" placeholder="key1">
<input type="text" id="key2" placeholder="key2">
<input type="text" id="key3" placeholder="key3">
<button onclick="jsonSend()">Save</button>
<p id="demo"></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's because you are trying to concatenate the new DOM object to a string and insert it into the document with `.innerHTML`, which only works with strings. Separate those two actions and append the DOM ojbect, rather than setting it into the document with `.innerHTML`.

```js
var obj, myJSON, showJSON, textSC, text2, outObj;

function jsonSend(){
    obj = {};
    obj.key1 = document.getElementById("key1").value;
    obj.key2 = document.getElementById("key2").value;
    obj.key3 = document.getElementById("key3").value;

    //storing data
    myJSON = JSON.stringify(obj);
    //localStorage.setItem("testJSON", myJSON);

    //new button
    showJSON = document.createElement("button");
    showJSON.setAttribute("id", "showJSON");
    textSC = document.createTextNode("Show info");
    showJSON.appendChild(textSC);
    showJSON.addEventListener("click", showFunc);
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = 
       "data stored successfully... <br>"
    document.getElementById("demo").appendChild(showJSON);
}

function showFunc(){
    //text2 = localStorage.getItem("testJSON");
    outObj = JSON.parse(text2);
    console.log(outObj);
}
```

```html
<h2>Enter keys</h2>
<input type="text" id="key1" placeholder="key1">
<input type="text" id="key2" placeholder="key2">
<input type="text" id="key3" placeholder="key3">
<button onclick="jsonSend()">Save</button>
<p id="demo"></p>
```

Comment: i get an error in browser console as Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token u in JSON at position 0

Comment: That's a different problem that what you asked about.

Comment: Scott, after running your code in the first part it gets the 3 inputs but the second part and by clicking on the "Show info" button it will show the error as "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token u in JSON at position 0"

Comment: That's because `localStorage` is not supported in the Stack Overflow snippet environment, so I commented out the two lines in your code that use it. Again, I've answered the question you asked about why your button doesn't show. You can see from my code that I've shown what the problem is and how to solve that.